# Eclipse Hellos intrigation with jasper report

Tags: eclipse, jasper-reports

I have installed Jasper plugin for Eclipse using [this](http://jasperstudio.sourceforge.net/updates/site.xml) URL in *Help --> Install new software* menu, but when I'm editing a `*.jrxml` file I'm not getting any design view.

Did I do something wrong? I just want to do design in of report through Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have installed JasperSoft Studio plugin correctly, try navigating into 'Window' -> 'Show View' -> 'Other', select 'JasperSoft Studio' folder and then for example 'Preview'. See if that works, if not, you would have to reinstall and restart your eclipse ide.

Comment: Yes i'm getting the Preview option ofr that jrxml file but i'm not getting any design view

Comment: How about right clicking on the file, then 'Open with..' -> 'JasperReports Designer'? If that doesn't work for you, try to start eclipse from command line and watch the messages while you opening the file, this way maybe we'll find the problem

Comment: i'm not getting any option like 'jasperReportDesigner' by clicking open with option. and i have run the Eclipse in commant prompt by writng this "C:\eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32\eclipse\eclipse" and open the file but i won't get any message in cmd prompt

Comment: I do have that option, I would guess you have a plugin wrongly installed, can you try reinstall?

Comment: Interesting, have you tried running a standalone jasper designer based on eclipse, you can find it here: http://jasperforge.org/projects/jaspersoftstudio, see if that works for you. What version of eclipse are you running?